# How can I filter products on multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a product page where the user has an option to filter on different boardgames. What I want to do is to give the user an option to filter on time, category of the game, number of players and age. When the user enters a checkbox on all 4 options there should be some games recommended based on the criteria. However when I check multiple boxes I get no result, what am I doing wrong? (I have more games in my file but post small amount)

Here's my code:

```js
// set up variables
var categoryFilters = [];
var categoryFilter;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('#products').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.boardgame',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    categoryFilter = categoryFilters.length ? categoryFilters.join(' ') : 'all';
    console.log(categoryFilter)
    var categoryResult = categoryFilter ? $this.is('[data-category*=' + categoryFilter + ']') : true;
    console.log(categoryResult)
    return categoryResult;
  }
});

// filter with checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $('#filtering input');

$checkboxes.change( function() {
  categoryFilters.length = 0;
  $checkboxes.each( function( i, elem ) {
    if ( elem.checked ) {
      categoryFilters.push( elem.value );
    }
    $container.isotope();
  });
});
```

```css
* { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

img{
    height: 265px;
    width: 265px;
}
select, label, input { 
    font-size: 20px; 
}

label { 
    margin-right: 10px; 
}

.productbutton {
  background: #85bf31;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.6em 2em;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.productbutton:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 51, 109);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<div id="filtering" class="filterlist">
    <h4>Minutes</h4>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="15" /> tot 15 min <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="30" /> 15 - 30 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="60" /> 30 - 60 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="90" /> Meer dan 60 min. <span class="checkmark"></span></label>          

    <h4>Category</h4>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Strategie" /> Strategie <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Family" /> Familie <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Kaartspel" /> Kaart <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Coop" /> Coöperatief <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Deductief" /> Deductief <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Kinder" /> Kinder <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="Fantasy" /> Fantasy <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <h4>Players</h4>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1 <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2 <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3 <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4 <span class="checkmark"></span></label>

    <h4>Age</h4>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="8" /> 8 jaar <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="10" /> 10 jaar <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="12" /> 12 jaar <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="15" /> 15 jaar <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
        <label class="container"><input type="checkbox" value="18" /> 18 jaar <span class="checkmark"></span></label>
</div>


<div>
    <div id="products">
    <ul class="products" id="products">
            <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 3 all 12 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Catan-Inkas-1.jpg" alt="Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas">
                    <h3>Catan Histories: Rise of the Inkas</h3>
                    <a href="catan-rise-of-the-incas.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 8 Family">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Carcassonne.jpg" alt="Carcassonne">
                    <h3>Carcassonne</h3>
                    <a href="carcassonne.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 12 Coop">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Paranormal-Detectives.jpg" alt="Paranormal Detectives">
                    <h3>Paranormal Detectives</h3>
                    <a href="paranormaldetectives.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 3 all 12 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/catan-cities-and-knights.jpg" alt="Catan: Cities & Knights Expansion">
                    <h3>Catan: Cities & Knights Expansion</h3>
                    <a href="catan-cities-and-knights.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="60 2 all 12 Coop">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Thanos-Rising.jpg" alt="Thanos Rising – Avengers: Infinity War">
                    <h3>Thanos Rising – Avengers: Infinity War</h3>
                    <a href="thanos-rising.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 2 all 12 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Marco-Polo-II.jpg" alt="Marco Polo II: In the Service of the Khan">
                    <h3>Marco Polo II: In the Service of the Khan</h3>
                    <a href="marco-polo-2-in-the-service-of-the-khan.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 2 all 15 Fantasy">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/dune.jpg" alt="Dune">
                    <h3>Dune</h3>
                    <a href="dune.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="60 1 all 15 Deductief">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Chronicles.jpg" alt="Chronicles of Crime">
                    <h3>Chronicles of Crime</h3>
                    <a href="chronicles-of-crime.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 8 Family">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/Kingdom-Builder-Family-Box.jpg" alt="Kingdom Builder Family Box">
                    <h3>Kingdom Builder Family Box</h3>
                    <a href="kingdom-builder-family-box.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="15 3 all 8 Family">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/just-one.jpg" alt="Just One">
                    <h3>Just One</h3>
                    <a href="just-one.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="60 3 all 15 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/AGOT-Catan-Brotherhood-of-the-watch.jpg" alt="A Game of Thrones Catan – Brotherhood of the Wall">
                    <h3>A Game of Thrones Catan – Brotherhood of the Wall</h3>
                    <a href="a-game-of-thrones-catan-brotherhood-of-the-watch.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="90 1 all 12 Deductief">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/jacktheripper.jpg" alt="Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective: Jack the Ripper & West End Adventures">
                    <h3>Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective: Jack the Ripper & West End Adventures</h3>
                    <a href="sherlock-holmes-jack-the-ripper.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="60 2 all 12 Coop">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/unlock.jpg" alt="Unlock!">
                    <h3>Unlock!</h3>
                    <a href="unlock.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 1 all 8 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/pandemic-inthelab.jpg" alt="Pandemic: In the Lab">
                    <h3>Pandemic: In the Lab</h3>
                    <a href="pandemic-in-the-lab.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boardgame" data-category="30 2 all 8 Strategie">
                    <li>
                    <img src="img/pandemic.jpg" alt="Pandemic">
                    <h3>Pandemic</h3>
                    <a href="pandemic.html" class="productbutton">Meer info</a> 
                    </li>
                    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you have a problem with your tag ul   its never closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the problem :

```
categoryFilter = categoryFilters.length ? categoryFilters.join(' ') : 'all';
```

You're trying to join every filter in the same order user clicks on checkboxes but there is an exception.
Consider this `data-category` as below:

```
data-category="90 3 all 12 Strategie"
```

This product will only be displayed when user clicks on filter `90` and then `3` and so on ...
But what if user clicks on `90` filter and then `Strategie`. The code will generate `90 Strategie` string. So there will be no products.
To fix this problem, you need to check for every `categoryFilter` on your `data-category` :

```
function checkCategory(element) {
      const cat = element.attr('data-category');
      let flag = true;
      for(i=0; i<categoryFilters.length; i++) {
        if(!cat.includes(categoryFilters[i])) {
          flag = false;
        } 
      }
      return flag;
}
```

And then use it :

```
var categoryResult = categoryFilter ? checkCategory($this) : true;
```

### [Live code on codepen](https://codepen.io/mostafa-es/pen/OJbqNwW)

---

Here is the complete JS file along with above changes:

```
// set up variables
var categoryFilters = [];
var categoryFilter;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('#products').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.boardgame',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    categoryFilter = categoryFilters.length ? categoryFilters.join(' ') : 'all';
var categoryResult = categoryFilter ? checkCategory($this) : true;
    return categoryResult;
  }
});

function checkCategory(element) {
  const cat = element.attr('data-category');
  let flag = true;
  for(i=0; i<categoryFilters.length; i++) {
    if(!cat.includes(categoryFilters[i])) {
      flag = false;
    } 
  }
  return flag;
}

// filter with checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $('#filtering input');

$checkboxes.change( function() {
  categoryFilters.length = 0;
  $checkboxes.each( function( i, elem ) {
    if ( elem.checked ) {
      categoryFilters.push( elem.value );
    }
    $container.isotope();
  });
});
```

Comment: Mosrainis, thank you for the support and the very clear answer in what I did wrong. The code works exactly as how I intended it to work!

Comment: @PHV You're welcome my friend, please accept this answer by click on big gray check button on its left side.